# Greedy Algorithm - Where I need to put those object?

Tags: java, algorithm, swing, object, greedy

I'm doing a little personal project and I need your help.

What I'm doing is that I've a list of Object (I call it bloc) which has a random size (width and height) and a also a random number. I have it into an ArrayList.

What I'm trying to do now is that I want to put those blocks into a ribbon : left is my ribbon and right are my blocs

[My window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TE4pP.png)

What I need to do is making the most optimal choice and to place all the bloc in the ribbonso as to minimize the height.

The problem is that :

[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sev8P.png)

When I want to place the A Bloc, I check 1st if there is some place at the number 1, obviously there is no place, then where should I check ? Number 2 ? Number 3 ?

Cordially

Comment: I don't think *ribbon* is a good name for the area you want to place the blocks in. Anyways, look up the *rectangle packing problem*.

Comment: Straight off the top of my head - I might consider using a `Map` of some kind and store the blocks based on their sizes, this would make the lookups much simpler and you could filter it so it only returns blocks within a given size range if needed

Comment: have a no clue with the `Map` I never used it.. i'll check the rectangle packing problem